# VS2012: Can't attach profiler. Can't load assembly VSPerfControl.Interop Version=11.0.0.0

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, profiling

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 (11.0.61219.00) Update 5 on Windows 7 Professional SP1.  I'd like to profile NUnit tests, which I've done in the past using VS2010 on a different system.  This is the first time I've tried this on this box, which has a fairly fresh VS2012 install.  When I try to attach the profiler to a running process using the Analyze | Profiler | Attach/Detach menu option, I get a dialog box containing the following error message:

**Could not load file or assembly 'VSPerfControl.Interop, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.**

I've done the following diagnostics:

- Verified that VSPerfControl.Interop.dll exists in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools with file version 11.0.50727.1
- Made sure I'm running Visual Studio in elevated (Administrator) mode
- Added the above directory to my system's PATH variable
- Checked C:\Windows\assembly and did not see the DLL loaded in the GAC

I haven't found any helpful posts on this, so I'm hoping someone here can help me figure out what's wrong.

**Update**:

The final solution to this problem can be found in HelpfulPaul's post below, **in the comments**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same issue. I used the VS cmd prompt to fix.

1. Go to the start menu -> all programs -> Visual Studio 2015 -> Visual
   Studio tools
2. Open the Developer command prompt
3. Change folders to the directory you listed above by using the
   command: cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools
4. Use the command: gacutil /i VSPerfControl.Interop.dll
5. Restart Visual Studios

Comment: This did get me past the error - thank you!  But now after attaching I get a dialog saying "PRF0010:Launch aborted - Unable to start vsperfmon.exe".  

If I try to start vsperfmon.exe from the command prompt, I get "Error VSP1398: The monitor was unable to install the VS performance driver.  The system cannot find the file specified. Consider using the /Admin:Driver,Install option of VSPerfCmd from an elevated environment.  Profiling cannot continue."

Comment: I had a similar problem but can't remember the exact error. It turned out VS never installed my performance tools. If I recall correctly inside VS's folder there's an exe I had to run that was like "VS performance tools with update 1" or something like that.

Comment: That was it!  I ran the file **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\Setups\vs_profiler_x64_enu.exe** and an installer for the VS2012 profiler ran.  Afterwards, I can attach and profile no problem.  Thank you for the full and final solution to my problem!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't use the Test Explorer which have direct connection with the profiler.

In Visual Studio 2012 and upwards you have a test explorer that can handle different 3rd party test frameworks, among them NUnit.  What you need to do is to either add a NUnit test adapter to your project (as a nuget package) or to Visual Studio (as a vsix extension).  Once you have done that, you will see your tests in the Visual Studio Test Explorer.

Profiling is then available from the Test Explorer as a context sensitive menu item.
[image: Profile test from Test Explorer]

There are 2 versions of the NUnit Test Adapter, on for NUnit V2 and one NUnit V3.
The corresponding NUnit adapters for VS can be found here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d  and https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d.

Comment: I do have the NUnit Test Adapter v2.0.0 installed and am using NUnit v2.6.3.  I can see and run NUnit tests from the Test Explorer, but I have no option to profile them.

Comment: Do you mean that context menu item is greyed out?

Comment: No, I mean there there is no option on the context menu.